# Exception when generating an Excel document from a Repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, repeater

I have pretty much followed this thread [Export to Excel from a Repeater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438184/export-to-excel-from-a-repeater), however, I get an exception saying

```
155|error|500|Control 'XXX' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.|
```

The LinkButton is defined in the HeaderTemplate, so how do I fix this problem?

**Updated:** The form tag is in the master page with runat="server"

Comment: How exactly does the HTML interpreter result in having a `<asp:LinkButton>` not get dereferenced as a `<a>` in the markup that's going to be exported? Maybe you should show the code that's supposedly writing the Excel document?

Comment: Is your repeater located within a `form` tag on your page?

Comment: I think the most likely error is that the <form> tag in the master page (or whatever page) doesn't have a runat="server" attribute? Can you post some code to help us pin-point the error?

Answer (score 1):

When You have Repeater control on the Master page and in that repeater control if you have Linkbutton or any other controls so you can use this code it may help you..I have used this code in Export to Excel

```
form.Controls.Add(this.rptChDashboard);

        this.Controls.Add(form);

        form.RenderControl(htmlTextWrite);``
```

Answer (score 0):

How it is said in the exception. "Place control inside a form tag with runat=server."

```
<form runat="server">
   <asp:Repeater>
      ...
   </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Or do some magic with [Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9ewz1aa%28vs.71%29.aspx) (not recommended)